# Grass exploding command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering how to detect grass and dirt blocks under a player and summon a tnt under them. I tried some things on my own and managed to set off a tnt at the player location, but I cannot summon it when the player is on the grass.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

To do this command, have this command in an always active repeating command block:

```
/execute at @a if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:grass_block run summon tnt ~ ~ ~
```

The `@a` part checks all players. The `if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:grass_block` checks if a player is on a grass block. The last part, `run summon tnt ~ ~ ~` summons a tnt at the player who was on a grass block. I hope this helps.

Comment: I thought numerical IDs are no longer supported. `minecraft:grass_block` was the correct way.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Oh! Oops! I will edit my post to correct that.